# how can I make the elements in a jQuery UI sortable container be freely draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Basically, I want to be able to freely drag items in a container and leave them at whatever position I desire..  However, if there are two items touching each other, dragging the one on the right towards the one on the left should cause the two to swap positions (hence sortability)...

However, if I do:

```
container.sortable({axis: 'x'});
item_1.draggable({axis: 'x'});
item_2.draggable({axis: 'x'});
container.append(item_1);
container.append(item_2);
```

then they are not sortable, just draggable...  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [`refresh`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-refresh) method?

> Refresh the sortable items. Custom trigger the reloading of all sortable items, causing new items to be recognized.

This should be called after you append the new elements.

Comment: Yeah, it does not work.  It seems that sortable no longer behaves once items in the container are freely draggable...